# Custom Map Mode in the Maps component

Tags: sxa

We want to declare our own map type, so that we can use a more minimal map than the road map; akin to something created using https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

The map mode can be defined in Sitecore:

e.g.

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Maps/Enums/Map Modes/OurMap
```

but it looks like `Sitecore.XA.Feature.Maps.Repositories.MapsRepository.MapMode` reads it from data source but then casts it to a `MapModes` enum.  This enum is later ToString'd in `GetJsonDataProperties` and this appears to be the only place the enum appears to be used.

It looks like we have to specify our own `MapsRepository` and override `GetJsonDataProperties` (where `MapMode` is ToString'd) just to set our own map mode.

Is there another way to reduce the features used on a map without affecting the existing MapModes?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map mode string which is passed to the `component-map.js` and later on passed to `google-maps-connector.js` or `bing-maps-connector.js` depending on what map provider are you using. This mode is next used to create a certain map and inform Google or Bing map in which mode render.

If you want to extend Google or Bing with an additional mode which recently becomes available for one of those then yes - your thinking is correct. I would:

1. Create new repository which is inheriting from MapsRepository
2. Override just MapMode property (it's virtual as most of the things in SXA)
3. Replace current IMapsRepository implementation which is in the container with your one.

There is one more way - if you always want to use this new map mode then override `component-map.js` and just hardcode this mode there (line 197). In that case, you don't need any backend code changes.